# How i make the Publisher certificate to be installed into 'Trusted Publishers' by default?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, certificate

I make a certificate in PowerShell.
First is the root and second i want the Publisher.

I export the certificates to a '*.pfx' file and when i install from that, the Root is put to Root folder and is good but the Second is going to Public and not to 'Trusted Publishers'.

How i can make the second to be installed to 'Trusted Publishers' by default?

If is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple function with the powershell:

```
$in_cert = "C:\Users\Marian\Desktop\Pfx Certificate.pfx";
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString;

# Read the pfx certificate data:
$pfx = (Get-PfxData -FilePath $in_cert -Password $password -ErrorAction Stop);

# Get the root and publisher certificate:
$root = $pfx.OtherCertificates[0];
$publisher = $pfx.EndEntityCertificates[0];

# Add the root:
$rootStore = Get-Item "Cert:\CurrentUser\Root";
$rootStore.Open('ReadWrite');
$rootStore.add($root);
$rootStore.close();

# Add the publisher:
$rootStore = Get-Item "Cert:\CurrentUser\TrustedPublisher";
$rootStore.Open('ReadWrite');
$rootStore.add($publisher);
$rootStore.close();

Pause;
```

To skip the "Root Warning" use the "Cert:\LocalMachine" and "Run As Administrator".